Why is my navbar's styling not staying consistent across pages?
So I have been fiddling around with my site on Nekoweb, trying to fix the navigation bar. I have styled it already with css. The styling seems to work just fine on index.html (my main/home page). However, when I link the stylesheet on other pages, such as the gallery, the styling does not get applied fully, and thus does not stay consistent. How do I fix this?
The navbar appears horizontally, just as I want it to. However, stuff like the font size does not change for some reason. On the home page, it is 18px, but on other pages it looks more like 12px.
Here is the snippet for said navbar on index page:


.nav-list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav-item {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}
.nav item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
}
<navbar>
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="site.org/index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="site.org/gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="site.org/contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</navbar>



And here is the snippet for the gallery page:


        <navbar>
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="site.org/index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="site.org/gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="site.org/contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </navbar>




Does your other page also have some different styles used ? Post the CSS and HTML of your other page also where the navabar is not as home page

Nope, the styles should be the same...I have linked to the same stylesheet for all the pages.

Please edit your question to show us the HTML for the gallery page.

@kmoser Just did.

You can follow @devindi-peiris ' answer from below, which says you have a typo in your css style rule and check if that resolves your issue.

Please edit your question to provide a minimal, reproducible example of the problem. The examples you gave are not sufficient to reproduce either a working or a non-working page.

@kmoser I am confused, how would I do that with my question?

Font size change could happen because of the typo in your code. In CSS it seems you missed the "-". (.nav-item a)
.nav-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
}

